# Stop Timer in another class

Tags: c#, events, timer

I have a program that sends and receives messages over serial.

I have this Sender class:

```
  public class Sender
  {
    private System.Timers.Timer _responseTimer;

    public Sender(SerialPort sp)
    {
      _serialPort = sp;
      _responseTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    }

    public void Attach(ISenderObserver iso)
    {
      _responseTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(iso.ResponseTooSlowEvent);
    }

    public void SendCommand(String command)
    {
       //start response timeout timer
      _responseTimer.AutoReset = false;
      _responseTimer.Enabled = true;
      _serialPort.Write(command);
    }
  }
```

And then I have this receiving class:

```
  public class Receiver : ISenderObserver
  {
    private static bool _continue;
    private static SerialPort _serialPort;
    private Thread _receiveThread;

    public Receiver(SerialPort sp)
    {
      _serialPort = sp;
      _continue = true;
      _serialPort.Open();
      //Start the receiving thread
      _receiveThread = new Thread(Receive);
      _receiveThread.Start();
    }

    public void Receive()
    {
      while (_continue)
      {
        String receivedMessage = _serialPort.ReadLine();
        //parse received message
      }
    }

    public void ResponseTooSlowEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      Console.Write("\nToo Slow!");
    }
  }
```

And this interface:

```
  public interface ISenderObserver
  {
    void ResponseTooSlowEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e);
  }
```

They are called like this in their main controller:

```
  sender = new Sender(_serialPort);
  receiver = new Receiver(_serialPort);
  sender.Attach(receiver);
```

The reason for the timer is that I want the program to abort its waiting for a certain message if it takes too long, thereby avoiding a deadlock if it gets disconnected.

I thereby want to stop the timer within the Receiver-class as soon as line:

```
String receivedMessage = _serialPort.ReadLine();
```

is finished.

How can I do this without having dependencies all over the place?

Comment: use the debugger.. also are you aware that doing it in new Threads is probably where the issue is happening.. when are you stopping the timer as well as doing the locking..?

Comment: I cannot use debugger at runtime since it is for an embedded system.

Can you be more specific of what you mean with "new Threads" causing the issue?

I want to stop the timer within the Receiver-class as soon as line:
String receivedMessage = _serialPort.ReadLine();
is finished

Comment: so you can't put the code in a `ConsoleApp` to test the code / methods..?

Comment: Yes, I could if bypass the serialport and simulate it with a sleep delay or something. But my question is about the best practice on how to call a timer from elsewhere. The debugger wont tell me that.

Comment: no the debugger won't so do a google search on `C# using timer in multiple threads`